# How to avoid crashes in tableView(_:cellForRowAt)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the Fabric, I see a lot of crashes in the "`tableView(_:cellForRowAt)`" section. There is not a certain scenario for this exceptions. Anytime and in the any screen it can occur.There is no data for analysing the crashes. Only I know there are  crashes in "`tableView(_:cellForRowAt)`".

I want to prevent this kind of exceptions although I do not know the root cause. Can I use a method like preventing NullPointer Exception (if (!null)) ?

Below two crashes in the different code sections ;

```
let XXX = Constants.sharedInstance.url+"/service/photo/"+userdas[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id!+"/"+userdas[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].photo!+"/2"
```

and

```
self.notificationModel[indexPath.row].userNot.XXX?.XXXImageView = image
```

Comment: Please add the code for your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt)` method to the question

Comment: Probably you're making some explicit or implicit force-unwraps in your method and that cause a crash. Add the code of your method so we could say for sure.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Two crashes in the different code sections ; 1- let XXX=Constants.sharedInstance.url+"/service/photo/"+userdas[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id!+"/"+userdas[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].photo!+"/2"

2- self.notificationModel[indexPath.row].userNot.XXX?.XXXImageView = image

Comment: @YuryImashev I added the lines that crashes occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it's clear that you're making a couple of explicit force unwraps that could lead you to crash.

```
userdas[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].id!

userdas[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].photo!

self.notificationModel[indexPath.row].userNot.XXX?.XXXImageView
```

I guess that in the third case `XXXImageView` is implicitly unwrapped `UIImageView` that also might be `nil`.

To avoid the crash in your first section you can use a `guard`

```
guard let id = userdas[indexPath.row].id, 
      let photo = userdas[indexPath.row].photo else {
    return 
}
let XXX = Constants.sharedInstance.url+"/service/photo/"+id+"/"+photo+"/2"
```

I'm not sure what you're doing in the second section, but you just need to check that you unwrapped parameters aren't `nil` as well

Comment: Thank you very much  @YuryImashev

Comment: @AshleyMills Sure! Thanks for the advice, answer updated